# Why does Xorg consumes a lot of CPU after installing NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg

I recently installed the NVIDIA drivers following the instructions on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_10) link in order to setup TensorFlow for deep learning.

Ever since then, Xorg and system-journald started consuming CPU excessively. I ran the following commands in hopes of troubleshooting the issue:

Edit: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is being spammed with this message:

`(EE) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Read error 9`

Full stack trace:

```
[    18.734] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    18.734] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    18.735] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Toshiba input device (/dev/input/event6)
[    18.735] (**) Toshiba input device: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.735] (**) Toshiba input device: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    18.735] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Toshiba input device'
[    18.736] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 54 paused 0
[    18.736] (**) Toshiba input device: always reports core events
[    18.736] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    18.736] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    18.736] (II) event6  - Toshiba input device: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    18.736] (II) event6  - Toshiba input device: device is a keyboard
[    18.736] (II) event6  - Toshiba input device: device removed
[    18.736] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input13/event6"
[    18.736] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Toshiba input device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[    18.736] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.736] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.737] (II) event6  - Toshiba input device: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    18.737] (II) event6  - Toshiba input device: device is a keyboard
[    19.637] randr: falling back to unsynchronized pixmap sharing
[    25.920] (EE) BUG: triggered 'if (priv->num_active_touches == 0)'
[    25.921] (EE) BUG: ../../src/synaptics.c:2958 in UpdateTouchState()
[    25.921] (EE) 
[    25.921] (EE) Backtrace:
[    25.921] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x5635c31fb8cd]
[    25.921] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7fa06d0bb000+0x4914) [0x7fa06d0bf914]
[    25.921] (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7fa06d0bb000+0x6802) [0x7fa06d0c1802]
[    25.921] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5635c3043000+0x1baa43) [0x5635c31fda43]
[    25.921] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5635c3043000+0x1bd141) [0x5635c3200141]
[    25.921] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5635c3043000+0x1ba88e) [0x5635c31fd88e]
[    25.922] (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fa079b91000+0x76db) [0x7fa079b986db]
[    25.922] (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (clone+0x3f) [0x7fa0798c188f]
[    25.922] (EE) 
[    26.934] (EE) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Read error 19
```

```
thanos@ubuntu-thanos:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
top - 15:18:49 up 41 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.97, 3.29, 3.26
Tasks: 295 total,   3 running, 246 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 20.0 us, 50.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 29.0 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8079992 total,   123892 free,  2329232 used,  5626868 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8299516 total,  8299516 free,        0 used.  5399288 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                   
 1181 root      20   0  354284  73548  44436 R 127.2  0.9  49:31.12 Xorg                                                                                                                      
  286 root      19  -1  345032 132712 131564 R  97.3  1.6  37:02.84 systemd-journal                                                                                                           
  962 syslog    20   0  263036   4120   3544 S  48.8  0.1  18:49.22 rsyslogd                                                                                                                  
  ...
```

```
thanos@ubuntu-thanos:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Mar 24 15:20:09 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.39       Driver Version: 418.39       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 950M    On   | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   71C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    387MiB /  4046MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1181      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            42MiB |
|    0      1229      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          65MiB |
|    0      1494      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           115MiB |
|    0      1695      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         119MiB |
|    0      2455      G   ...uest-channel-token=11843812546895049575    40MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
thanos@ubuntu-thanos:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Asv00001179sd0000F842bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

If you require any other information, please let me know. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Uninstal xf86-input-synaptics. GNOME (GTK3) switched from the synaptics to the libinput driver and removing that package seems to help for some. Please comment if this worked or did not work for you.

Comment: I uninstalled xserver-org-input-synaptics following the instructions here: https://github.com/siongui/userpages/blob/master/content/articles/2018/05/11/ubuntu-linux-18.04-run-out-of-disk-space%25en.rst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found after following the instructions on [this link](https://github.com/siongui/userpages/blob/master/content/articles/2018/05/11/ubuntu-linux-18.04-run-out-of-disk-space%25en.rst).

Also there is a [bug submission](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1766358) on Ubuntu.

TLDR: `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

Comment: Nice :) have an upvote and accept your own answer when you can!

Comment: Thank you, I can accept my answer in 2 days.

Comment: @Rinzwind I think two days has passed...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix some people :D

Comment: I think I am late, but the answer has been accepted. Apologies xd